# iOS - Highlight One Word Or Multiple Words In A UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring

In my project, I'm making a small piece of functionality that allows a user to read a body of text (in a `UITextView`) faster by having one word being highlighted at a time, or even multiple if a user wants. One by one, each word in the `UITextView` should be highlighted at the speed the user sets.

Is there any way I could highlight the background of a word in a `UITextView`? I think it has something to do with attributed strings, but I can't find anything that highlights the background of an `NSString`.

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: may this answer help you use *textView.attributedText*
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49626125/5212377

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does have to do with attributed strings. It has nothing to do with NSString, because an attributed string is *not* an NSString; it is an NSAttributedString, or its mutable subclass NSMutableAttributedString. What you want to do is set the `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName` to a background color for the range of the desired word.

I should mention also that you can obtain snazzier effects by intervening in the Text Kit stack that constructs the UITextView's drawing system, as in this image where I'm drawing a rectangle around a word:

[image]

However, the background color should be enough to get you started.

Comment: How will I know the range of each word as I go through the `UITextView`?

Comment: That would be a different question. If you have a new question, ask a new question! I believe I've answered the question you did ask — namely, how to "highlight the background".

Comment: True, I'll look into it further. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @matt could you post the code related to "drawing a rectangle around a word" !

Comment: @saif I have posted that code, and I've written a book that explains it.